# How to assign Unknown class(Controller) as AnyObject to delegate of some other class? in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, uiviewcontroller

I need help rewriting this Objective-C method into Swift.

**Objective c code:**

```
- (void)pushViewControllerAnimatedWithMember:(Member *)member withSelf:(id)controller
{
    ZJMHomePageViewController *homePageViewController = [ZJMHomePageViewController new];
    homePageViewController.member = member;
    homePageViewController.delegate = controller;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:homePageViewController animated:YES];
}
```

**SwiftCode**:

```
func pushViewControllerAnimatedWithMember(member: Member, withSelf controller: AnyObject?)
{
    let homePageViewController : ZJMHomePageViewController = ZJMHomePageViewController.new()
    homePageViewController.member = member
    homePageViewController.delegate = controller // gives error as Not able to assign any object to delegate
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(homePageViewController,animated:true)
}
```

Comment: Are you sure `ZJMHomePageViewController` has a delegate property?  Can you post the declaration?

Comment: var delegate : RemoveMemberDelegate?

Answer (score 0):

delegate property type must be AnyObject so you can pass it ok. Basically, controller and delegate must be the same type or you'll need to add a cast (as) when assigning it's value